# React-Native navigate in createStackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to navigate When click to TouchableOpacity in createStackNavigator. But I can't do this.

return to me navigate is not a function

How can i do this?

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {       
      Login:{screen: Login },
      EditProfile:{screen:EditProfileScreen},
      Main:{screen: MainScreen , navigationOptions: {
       headerTitle: (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', width:100+"%"}}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{width:36,height:40,position:"absolute",right:10}} 
            onPress={()=> createStackNavigator.navigate("EditProfile")}
            >
                <AutoHeightImage width={36}  source={require('./img/user.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        ),
        headerLeft: null,
        headerTintColor: "white",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#34495e'
        } }},

    }, { initialRouteName:"Login "});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, however you've made a couple of small oversight within your code.

When declaring the `navigationOptions` for each screen, you have to make sure to pass the `navigation` argument so that you can call it within the `navigationOptions` block of code.

An example of this is given within `react-navigation` documents [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
createStackNavigator({
    Profile: {
        screen: ProfileScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: ${navigation.state.params.name}'s Profile'`,
        }),
    },
});
```

*Take note of the `({navigation})` parameter within the `navigationOptions` property.*

In your case, your code will need to be edited to this:

```
 Main: {
  screen: MainScreen,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 100 + '%' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ width: 36, height: 40, position: 'absolute', right: 10 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditProfile')}
        >
          <AutoHeightImage width={36} source={require('./img/user.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ),
  }),
}
```

***3 Things to note that I have changed:***

1. `({navigation})` was added as a param to `navigationOptions`.
2. The use of the `(` before the `{` when declaring the `navigationOptions`. As well as the subsequent closing brackets.
3. The `onPress` function was changed as well to utilize the `navigation` parameter.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No worries! :) Let me know if you run into any issues. I'll try my best to help.

Comment: Hi again , I have a problem :) I would like to take this.state.photo in const RootStact , but I cant

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to access any state variables straight from your RootStack! If you open a new issue with your code and link it to me here, I could possibly help out!